# SQL Server ISNULL not working

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I have the following query for SQL server:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CurrentVendorLastPurchCost, 0)) AS TheSum FROM VW_Report_AvailableInventory WITH(NOLOCK)
```

The table that I am running it on is empty. Given the ISNULL clause, I would expect it to return 0.

However, it returns NULL.

I have had a look at a number of posts and tried various different combinations of code, but none of them produce the result I want.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `ISNULL` inside `SUM`. Wrap it round the sum instead. Try.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CurrentVendorLastPurchCost), 0) AS TheSum FROM VW_Report_AvailableInventory WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 2):

As your table is empty then you haven't any value in there to apply `ISNULL` function and the result of `SUM` on empty set is `NULL`.
You shouldn't care about `null` values in summing. To solve your issue use:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CurrentVendorLastPurchCost), 0) AS TheSum
FROM VW_Report_AvailableInventory WITH(NOLOCK)
```